# Height of cell taller than cell contents - view rendering issue

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an odd problem I was hoping someone could perhaps explain. Searching yields nothing in this case.

If `heightForRowAtIndexPath` specifies a height which is taller than that of the contents drawn as a result of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then upon scrolling, once the view refreshes its contents, it won't draw some of the cell contents that I've rendered (each row height is dynamic). However, if I reduce the row height somewhat, everything will be rendered correctly.

Is there some documentation pertaining to this problem? Should `heightForRowAtIndexPath` always return the precise row height based on contents? For example, I just made the row heights rather large so I could always see the contents, but alas, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` wouldn't be called as many times as it should, and general rendering problems ensued.

Apologies for the fuzzy description, but perhaps those who have experienced the same problem could offer some insight.

Cheers.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well, seems they changed something in 7.1 that handles how the cells are drawn. If the cell is bigger then the height that's supplied in heightForRowAtIndexPath: weird rendering things happen (cells become transparent / overlap etc) I have not found a workaround yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

If your cell content contains dynamic content which affects the height, you have to return different height values from heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Tableview calls heightForRowAtIndexPath many times so **don't do** any calculations inside heightForRowAtIndexPath, instead create an array which holds the calculated height values and simply return the values from the array.